# interfacing keyboard controller in assembly

Tags: assembly, keyboard

I'm trying to interface with my **keyboard controller** through ports
`64h` and `60h`. I've written assembly code compatible with **Borland
Turbo Assembler(TASM)** and **Linker(TLINK)** to do it.
I have tried to get enough info about interfacing a keyboard
controller from articles over the web but unfortunately no success
so far on getting my code to have the expected result.

Here is the summary of what I have done already:

1. I read **Status Register** by reading port `64h` and got the byte
      `(00010100b)` initially.
2. Before sending any command to the controller I have included
      a loop to wait for **IBF** flag *(Bit 1 of Status Register)* to make sure that it's cleared
      `(IBF = 0)`.
3. After the loop described above I have sent a simple command like
      `AAh`*(Controller Self Test)* or `ADh`*(Disable Keyboard Interface)* to
      the controller via port `64h`.
4. Included another loop after sending command to make sure and
      determine that **OBF** flag *(Bit 0 of Status Register)* is set `(OBF = 1)`.

and the problem rises right at this stage and when I check
the **Status Register** by reading port `64h` I can't see that
neither **OBF** nor **IBF** is updated by the controller as I suppose
at least **OBF** should be and what I get from **Status Register**
is the byte `(00011100b)` which says that a command was sent to the
controller as "bit 3" was set. Although just in command `ADh`*(Disable
Keyboard Interface)* I see that my keyboard stops responding.

And the info of the system I use:

- Pentium 4,
- Windows XP SP3,
- Windows Command Prompt(cmd),
- Borland Turbo Assembler(TASM) and Linker(TLINK) version 5,
- An FCR-8900 keyboard with a PS/2 connector,
- A USB Mouse connected to a second PS/2 port via a USB-2-PS/2,

The PS/2 ports are **6-pin DIN** as I believe and checked double time.

Despite of these PS/2 ports, I have used several snippets from
the net that report my system as an **AT system**, something that I
can't understand either.

I appreciate anyone sharing any kind of experience or help.
Thank you...

Comment: You need to run this program in a MS-DOS compatibility box if you want to have any hope of its working.  I'm amazed Windows lets you execute the `in` instruction *at all* when you run it from a regular command prompt.

Comment: Thank you @Zack for your quick comment, but my code supposed to run
in real mode not protected mode and from what I got by searching the
net, it is said that the windows command is itself emulated as DOS
or something like this sort of stuff. In addition I have tried what
you suggested before by running my program in **DOSBox-0.74**, but sadly
no success.

Comment: Yes, I know your program is supposed to run in real mode -- that was my point; the environment provided by XP's command prompt is protected mode.

Comment: What I actually meant by "DOS compatibility box" was Windows' own DOS compatibility mode: http://filext.com/faq/run_old_program_xp.php

Comment: Thanks for the link and for your clarification on "compatibility"
@zack, I tried it but the result is still the same and I think the
problem is in what you mentioned about Windows command(as sometime
called Windows DosBox) being in _protected mode_. Because as I stated
before, by sending **keyboard inhibition command(0xAD)** to keyboard controller
keyboard stops responding but only inside DOS window and when I click on 
another window like notepad keyboard is reacting to key hits.

Comment: Although I think like that I don't believe that way at all.
If thing were to be that much complicated for testing a real mode
program, then all these compilers and linker had to be useless.
Anyone writing some code(including students and novices like me) has to
check the EXE file compiled from the code to monitor the results and
obtain experience, and I don't think people have to have a DOS OS
installed or have a PC of ancient times to just simply test their codes
by restarting to enter to DOS environment to check the EXE file and
restarting back again to logon to main OS to edit the code.

Comment: *Because as I stated before, by sending **keyboard inhibition command(0xAD)** to keyboard controller keyboard stops responding but only inside DOS window and when I click on another window like notepad keyboard is reacting to key hits.*  -- Yes, that's expected behavior.  You can do what you like inside the DOS compatibility environment, but Windows won't let you take total control of the keyboard.  If you *really* want to code like it was 1984, you have to install an actual copy of MS-DOS, separate from Windows.

Comment: *If thing were to be that much complicated for testing a real mode program, then all these compilers and linker had to be useless.* -- Writing a real-mode program is a strange thing to want to do nowadays.  The development environment is geared for writing protected-mode Windows executables.

Comment: I appreciate showing patience and taking time for me @zack,
maybe you're right, but I have to learn the _Basics_
before getting myself geared in topics like "protected mode
programming" which is more than enough complex to me.  And about installing MS-DOS, maybe I have to do it some day
but for the time, that _really_ takes the cake.
Anyhow, thank you once more, I think this sort of problems
persists as long as lagging snippet_writers like me _grasping
at burnt straws..._

Comment: The protected-mode user space environment provided by Windows (or any other modern operating system) is **easier** to learn, and easier to work with, than the legacy DOS environment that you're trying to use. Even if you want to write your own operating system, literally the first thing the *bootloader* does nowadays is switch to protected mode, and if there's an 8042 keyboard controller behind ports 0x60 and 0x64, it's because the BIOS is faking it; a serious OS would want to bypass that. Are you a time traveller? I have a list of things that need fixed in the past...

Comment: No such luck @Zack that If I were...  
All right, I took the point, I'm determined to challenge this
_protected mysterious monster_.  
However, I figured out something about my question here though not sure.
I think I was wrong that I was expecting to see KBD controller's
OBF flag going high after issuing a command to, the controller won't and
should not wait after sending command until CPU reads its OBF flag then
the controller go on and run the command. In programming, One can step
CPU's instructions not peripheral systems like KBD Controller.

Comment: [continued...] In other words, we program the CPU not the KBD controller.  
It's like: you see a commander give the order to **ATTACK**, then expecting
soldiers to wait till commander says **I HEARD THAT YOU SAID ROGER, NOW FIGHT**
I mean as soon as you send the command, KBD controller run the command and
clears its OBF flag so it's hard to see `OBF = 1`.  
I hope I stated it clear enough.